# How is the JS object mutable if the writable property defaults to false

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to understand how the Object mutation in JS works. I came across the writable property on JS.

```
var x = {name:'JohnSnow'};

Object.defineProperty(x, 'name', {
   writable: false
};
```

Now changing the `name` property has no effect on the object `x`. This is understandable as I have changed its `writable` property to `false`.

However, all the docs that I read including (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties#Parameters) says that this property is `false` by default.

If the `writable` is set to `false` by default, shouldn't the object be immutable by default and should become mutable only after setting `writable` to `true`.

Am I wrong in understanding the concept of Object properties here, because I think all the objects in JS have this `config` and every object has `writable` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Object.defineProperty` should usually only be used when defining a *new* property - otherwise, the property descriptor object passed will often be partially ignored, as described in [step 2 of 9.1.6.3 ValidateAndApplyPropertyDescriptor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor) 
.

In step 2, the new descriptor, `desc`, will only be put as the new property descriptor if the current descriptor is undefined.

In step 6, an existing data property might be switched to become an accessor property (or the other way around), but

> Preserve the existing values of the converted property's [[Configurable]] and [[Enumerable]] attributes and set the rest of the property's attributes to their [default values](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-default-attribute-values).

Steps 7 and 8 do not change the current descriptor, they simply verify and return a value.

So, no matter the descriptor passed, if the property already exists on the object, the `writable` property (or its absence) of the "new" descriptor will be completely ignored.

---

`writable` does default to `false`, but *only* when using `Object.defineProperty`.

```js
var x = {};

Object.defineProperty(x, 'name', {
   value: 'foo'
});

x.name = 'bar';
console.log(x.name);
```

As you can see above, if you do not provide a `writable` property when calling `Object.defineProperty`, it will default to `false`. That's *all* it means - it's not specifying that properties are always non-writable by default, it's only specifying that properties are non-writable *when defining a property with* `Object.defineProperty`.

Object properties are writable when defining an object with an object literal, described in [12.2.6.7 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation *ObjectLiteral* : {}](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> 2. Perform ? PropertyDefinitionEvaluation of PropertyDefinitionList with arguments obj and true.

Which *eventually* leads you to:

[CreateDataProperty ( O, P, V )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createdataproperty)
:

> Let newDesc be the PropertyDescriptor { [[Value]]: V, **[[Writable]]: true**, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true }.

Comment: Nitpick: when you use `Object.defineProperty` to modify an existing property as seen in the question instead of newly defining or redefining one, it won’t act like `writable: false`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So shall this be understood that the entire concept of the object configuration comes in picture only when you once invoke the `defineProperty` or `defineProperties` method on Object.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari: Not really. Try `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, 'name')` without any `defineProperties`. The defaults are just different depending on the situation. For example, when you use a normal property in an object literal or assign a new property with `=`, that property is writable and enumerable. But if you define a class with `class`, the properties on the prototype from the methods in it are writable and *non*-enumerable.